# Simple dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

Check me out on this

```
languages = ['English', 'German', 'English', 'Italian', 'Italian', 'English', 'German', 'French']
```

I want to generate a frequency table out of it. So I did

```
freq = {}
for language in languages:
    if language in freq:
        freq[language] += 1
    else:
        freq[language] = 1
```

Which is correct

BUT I want to use count() wihthin a dictionary comprehension to solve it. I got it wrong for several tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned "dictionary comprehension", you could try:

```
>>> {k: languages.count(k) for k in dict.fromkeys(languages)}
{'English': 3, 'German': 2, 'Italian': 2, 'French': 1}
>>>
```

Or just:

```
>>> {k: languages.count(k) for k in languages}
{'English': 3, 'German': 2, 'Italian': 2, 'French': 1}
>>>
```

Or without dictionary comprehension you could try `dict(zip(...))` with `map(...)`:

```
>>> dict(zip(languages, map(languages.count, languages)))
{'English': 3, 'German': 2, 'Italian': 2, 'French': 1}
>>>
```

Or just `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(languages)
Counter({'English': 3, 'German': 2, 'Italian': 2, 'French': 1})
>>>
```

Comment: ```freq = dict(Counter(languages))``` Just figured that I can have an actual dictionary instead of an iterator.

Comment: @O'BrienZimeTaga yeap! that would work! please remember to upovte as well :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `Counter` from `collections`:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: languages = ['English', 'German', 'English', 'Italian', 'Italian', 'English', 'Ger
   ...: man', 'French']

In [3]: count = Counter(languages)

In [4]: count
Out[4]: Counter({'English': 3, 'German': 2, 'Italian': 2, 'French': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) class for this:

```
from collections import Counter
freq = Counter(languages)
```

Now freq will contain your languages in descending order of their occurrence in the languages list.